# Flash Builder 4 no longer... Building!

Tags: flash-builder, flashbuilder4, flashcatalyst

Flash Builder 4 has stopped building my apps.  I was working on a couple of projects.  When I debugged the app, none of my changes were reflected in the debug version.  I tried manually building, resetting all of my preferences, eventually Clean building the entire app.  This was a mistake.  FB4 threw out all the files it was supposed to be building (the .html wrapper, the swf file itself, and the swfobject.js file) and left me out to dry.  Now I have a couple thousand lines of code that does nothing.  When I try to run/debug I get the message: "Can't find file:[pathname/wrapper].html"

This is apparently a compatibility conflict with my system (2008 MacBook running Snow Leopard)  Everything works fine on my wife's laptop (identical installation of CS5).  How do I go about finding the conflict?  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling FB4 on my computer but still get the same message.

Thanks,

Jason M.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try clicking on your project then going to `Project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler` and see if all the HTML wrapper options at the bottom are checked off? You can also check the other options there, it could be possible that something in those settings changed? (If they are checked off already, try un-checking them and then selecting them again and applying the settings)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem simply by trashing the preference file.  It took some digging, but I found that Flash Builder's preference file is actually an eclipse preference file.  Anyway, for the time being FB is working just dandily (word?).